# Square packing variant

Tags: combinatorial-optimization

I saw the following problem and was looking for references about the problem. The problem is stated as

> “The green field is the empty area, the dark green 2x2 blocks are
> trees and the grey area is the off area. I’m wondering how to place
> the blocks in the field, while cutting the least amount of trees.”

with a picture (I've reduced the size)

[image]

As far as I can tell this is related to square packing (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems#Packing_squares) but there is the related problem of minimizing the number of trees cut. I also found this Stack Exchange answer which suggested some approaches (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213394/what-algorithm-can-be-used-for-packing-rectangles-of-different-sizes-into-the-sm) but it doesn't fit exactly.

Any insights would be useful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  For each size $s\in\{3,4,5\}$, let $n_s$ be the number of blocks of size $s$ to place. For each cell $(i,j)$ and each size $s \in \{3,4,5\}$, let binary variable $x_{i,j,s}$ indicate whether $(i,j)$ is the top left corner of a block of size $s$.  For each cell $(i,j)$, let $B_{i,j}$ be the set of blocks that cover that cell, and let binary variable $y_{i,j}$ indicate whether that cell is covered by some block.  For each tree $t$, let $C_t$ be the cells that are covered by that tree, and let binary variable $z_t$ indicate whether that tree is cut.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_t z_t$ subject to linear constraints
\begin{align}
\sum_{i,j} x_{i,j,s} &=n_s &&\text{for all $s$} \tag1 \\
\sum_{(i',j',s)\in B_{i,j}} x_{i',j',s} &=y_{i,j} &&\text{for all $(i,j)$} \tag2 \\
y_{i,j} &\le z_t &&\text{for all $t$ and $(i,j)\in C_t$} \tag3\\
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ places all $n_s$ blocks of size $s$.
Constraint $(2)$ prevents overlapping blocks.
Constraint $(3)$ enforces cutting a tree if some block covers a tree cell.

If I have entered the data correctly, the minimum turns out to be $13$, as shown here, where T indicates a surviving tree, C indicates a cut tree, $3\times 3$ blocks are red, $4\times 4$ blocks are orange, $5\times 5$ blocks are blue, and uncovered cells are green:
[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the order of magnitude of the resolution time for this instance?

Comment: How did you generate the visualization?

Comment: @fontanf It took 7 seconds.

Comment: @RyanHowe I used the SGPLOT procedure in SAS.

Comment: @RobPratt Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help. Where did you find this problem?

Comment: @RobPratt Someone posted it on Quora (https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-sort-64-different-sized-blocks-into-a-squared-area-so-that-they-fit-the-best-way-1). I thought it was interesting.